# How can I add specific values of textboxes in the Data grid (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have 5 TextBoxes and a Button, what I want is to display 4 out of 5 textboxes values in the data grid when the button is clicked. I am a new user so i can not attach the picture of the interface.

My text boxes are named as follows:

```
IDTextbox, titleText, QuantityTextbox, PriceTextbox, BrandTextbox
```

My button is named `AddButton`.

When I click on `AddButton`, the values from titleText, QuantityTextbox, PriceTextbox, BrandTextbox should be displayed in dataGrid.

I don't want to display the product id in the datagrid, instead I want a column with the header "Total_price". This column should display the total_price ie (`quantity * price`)

Also, I want to add the values every time a click the `AddButton`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding YourDataCollection}" />
<Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Id, 
        ElementName=DataGrid}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, 
        ElementName=DataGrid}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.BirthDate, 
        ElementName=DataGrid}" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do Some thing Like that.....

```
<TextBox Name="IDTextbox" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="en-US" />
<TextBox Name="titleText" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="en-US" />
<TextBox Name="QuantityTextbox" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="en-US" />
<TextBox Name="PriceTextbox" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="en-US" />
<TextBox Name="BrandTextbox" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" Language="en-US" />
<Button Content="Add new row" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="DataGrid1" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding TestBinding}" Margin="0,50,0,0" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Brand" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Brand}" Width="50"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=Title}" Width="130"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity}" Width="130"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Price}" Width="130"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = new Test { Brand= BrandTextbox.Text, Title= titleText.Text,
                Quantity = QuantityTextbox.Text, Price = PriceTextbox.Text };

        DataGridTest.Items.Add(data);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what if i want to add Up all the prices in the price column of dataGrid and show them below in a label? @jitendra

Comment: You can add one more row with grand total in data object... so do this--- data.add(new Test { Brand = "", Quality = "", Title = "Total" , Price = Data.Sub(l => l.Price)});  before line DataGridTest.Items.Add(data); @MohammadHaseeb . Currently i don't have visual Studio, so please let me know if u will find any issue...........

Comment: thanks for your help. This code has some errors there "Data.Sub(l => l.Price)"

Comment: U get it very right i just want to show the grand total at the bottom of the data grid

Comment: sorry use "Data.Sum(l => l.Price)" instead of "Data.Sub(l => l.Price)".... Thank You.... i have also found a useful thread for it ............ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484438/how-to-show-a-grand-total-by-adding-all-the-prices-in-the-datagrid-column-wpf

Answer (score 1):

in the Xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtID" Height="50"></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtQuantity" Height="50"></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtPrice" Height="50"></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtBrand" Height="50"></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtTitle" Height="50"></TextBox>
    <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Height="20">Click</Button>
    <DataGrid x:Name="gridTotal">

    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

in the windows Loaded event

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Title"))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("Title");
                }
                if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Quantity"))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
                }
                if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Price"))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("Price");
                }
                if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Brand"))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("Brand");
                }
                if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Total"))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add("Total");
                }

                gridTotal.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            }
            catch (Exception ec)
            {
                throw ec;
            }
        }
```

in Button click

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Title"] = txtTitle.Text;
            dr["Quantity"] = txtQuantity.Text;
            dr["Price"] = txtPrice.Text;
            dr["Brand"] = txtBrand.Text;
            dr["Total"] = Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text);

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

Comment: i want to add Up all the prices in the price column of dataGrid and show them at the bottom of the grid, can you please help me in this context?